# Safari display black screen when trying to play video in macOS

Tags: macos, safari, video

I'm trying to see a video in Coursera using Safari 15.0 in my MacBook Air but it only shows a black screen, the audio works fine. The strange thing is that YouTube works, it is just some websites that this happens.

I found that this [bug](https://www.iphonetricks.org/how-to-fix-safari-videos-black-screen-bug/) happens in iOS and there is a way to fix it. But I can't seem to find a way to solve it in macOS (I'm using the latest version 11.6).

The video works just fine in Google Chrome and I already tried to disable all extensions.

[image]

Comment: Have you cleared cookies and caches for the Coursera web site? If this happened to me, that would be the first thing I would do, and then fully quit/restart Safari.

Comment: I've tried that. Unfortunately it didn't work